# iPhone Launch image for a landscape based application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5

The problem is that the launch image I have set up isn't showing up I speculate its because its dimension are for portrait but since its landscape based it isn't showing up and I have set up all my launch images correctly on the asset catalog now the thing is I don't know if I'm supposed to set it up as portrait under Deployment info and later then coding for it to once it has completely launched and loaded to stay in landscape and not rotate to portrait I notice that on my asset catalog I don't have an image with the dimensions 320x480 it never asked me for it you know how it has slots well in my project it never gave me one pertaining such dimensions (320x480) it only had two slots for iPhone portrait which were "@2x" (640x960) and "R4" (640 x1136)

Update 
I tried changing the dimension from 640x960 to 960x640 but I got an error as soon as I added to the catalog because those weren't the right dimensions

Answer (score 2):

More Details : [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12)

[image]

portrait only available in xcode for launch image but you can customize your image. create image landscape mode the portrait size through attached to xcode. it's works perfectly and display image as landscape

Create launch images in different sizes for different devices. Launch images for all devices must include the status bar region. Create launch images in the following sizes:

For iPhone 5 and iPod touch (5th generation):

640 x 1136 pixels
For other iPhone and iPod touch devices:

640 x 960 pixels
320 x 480 pixels (standard resolution)

Comment: I couldn't really follow you so customize my image for landscape mode while still consisting of the same portrait dimensions?

Comment: iPhone and iPod touch Portrait 320 x 480 pixels, 640 x 960 pixels (@2x) Landscape Not supported

Comment: I notice that on my asset catalog I don't have an image with the dimensions 320x480 it never asked me for it you know how it has slots well in my project it never gave me one pertaining such dimensions (320x480) it only had two slots for iPhone portrait which were "@2x" (640x960) and "R4" (640 x1136)

Answer (score 1):

If at all you still want to view the splash screen in landscape mode you have to design the image in such a way as we cannot change the behavior of the splash screen.

Instead of designing the image as 640x960, design it as 960x640 and your problem will get solved.

Edit:
This is sample splash image in portrait dimension but designed in landscape view
    [image]

All the best.

Comment: Yeah man I've tried that and as soon as I add it to the asset catalog it denies the image for it doesn't consist of the correct dimensions unless theirs a different way of adding it in??

Comment: The dimension of the image be 640x960 but u design the image in 960x640(landscape mode)

Comment: yeah its still shows up as a black screen could it be maybe because I haven't done the iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone only uses ONE launch image -- portrait

only the iPad supports orientations during launch

---

what many do:

- have no launch image
- make sure applicationDidFinishLaunching returns as soon as possible(!)
- show your own splash screen view
- do your real loading only THEN

Comment: hum but then it wouldn't be accepted by apple because it requires you to at least have one launch image no? or it wouldn't matter?

Comment: it'd be black or a logo. Mind im not recommending this. but iPhone has no landscape

Comment: so if iPhone has no landscape for launch image and the program only supports landscape orientation then the whole launch image set up for it would be obsolete?

Answer (score 0):

I was going to comment on @Warrior's answer but StackOverflow won't let me.

You shouldn't need to specify an iPhone 5 optimised image (I haven't for my app and it works), although if this is a new app I would recommend it.

Are you running it on an iOS 7 device?
I have noticed that Xcode allows you to add a 1x and 2x image specific to iOS 5 & 6 devices.

[image: iOS6 Launch Image]

Otherwise all I can suggest is checking your dimensions (it must be a portrait sized image 640x960px) and be placed in the '2x' slot) and also make sure your info plist is pointing to the correct location.

[image: Launch Image Selection]

Then as others have suggested, all you need to do to get a landscape image is have artwork that is rotated 90 degrees when your image is portrait.

Comment: yeah I'm running it on a iOS 7 device although let me just double check everything regarding dimension and p list

Comment: probably has to do something with the p list cause i haven't done anything to that and my dimensions are good

Answer (score 0):

The screen size and Icon size for iOS.

ICONS (iPhone and iPad)

29 x 29pt (1x and 2x)
40 x 40pt (1x and 2x)
50 x 50pt (1x and 2x)
57 x 57pt (1x and 2x)
60 x 60pt (2x)
72 x 72pt (1x and 2x)
76 x 76pt (1x and 2x)

NOTE: 2x is double the size of 1x images

SCREEN SIZE

iPhone 4s and earlier (3.5 inch)
320 x 480 pts

Retina
640 x 960 pts

iPhone 5 (4 inch)
320 x 568 pts

retina
640 x 1136 pixels

iPad protrait
768 x 1004

retina
1536 x 2008

iPad Landscape
1024 x 748

retina
2048 x 1496

OTHER IMAGE SLICING

All image slicing requires both 1x and 2x to work perfectly for retina and non retina displays.

NOTE: 2x is double the size of 1x images.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you add both a portrait and landscape image to the asset catalog and the device chooses which one to use based on the current device orientation.

If your app only supports landscape then you only need to provide a landscape image, as long as you set the "Device Orientation" in your info plist to be "Landscape Left" and "Landscape Right" ONLY.

In that case, the user will always be presented with a landscape launch image and this will indicate to them that they need to rotate their device.

- Anthony

Comment: hum on my asset catalog I only added iPhone portrait ios7 Launch images so on my asset catalog Launch images I would just add them in with their certain dimensions?? and yeah on my plist I have specified landscape left and landscape right only

Comment: The iPhone only uses ONE launch image -- portrait

Comment: Sorry I missed the part of the question where the OP stated it was an iPhone app. Yes, on the iPhone you must use a portrait sized image, but with landscape content.